# How to throw custom exception if arguments are passed to class

Tags: python, oop

I have a coffee class with a decorator. Is it possible to check that the Americano should come first? And at the same time it must be once

```
class Americano(TO_ADD):
    price = 60

class TO_ADD:
    def calculate_cost(self):
        return self.__class__.price

class Decorator(TO_ADD):
    def __init__(self, addition):
        self.components = addition
    def calculate_cost(self):
        return self.components.calculate_cost() + TO_ADD.calculate_cost(self)
 
class Cardamom(Decorator):
    price = 7
    def __init__(self, addition):
        Decorator.__init__(self, addition)

class Syrop(Decorator):
    price = 10
    def __init__(self, addition):
        Decorator.__init__(self, addition)
```

Correct example

```
res = Cardamom(Syrop(Syrop(Syrop(Americano()))))
print(res.calculate_cost())
```

Incorrect example. In this case I need to trow exception(by myself). How to do it?

```
res = Cardamom(Syrop(Syrop(Americano(Syrop()))))
print(res.calculate_cost())
```

Comment: Have you actually tried the second example? It should already raise an exception because `Americano()` takes no arguments. So your problem is already solved.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes i tried but i need to trow custom exception by myself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a constructor for `TO_ADD` with no parameters, it'll throw a`TypeError` if you pass one

```
class TO_ADD:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Or if you need a custom exception :

```
class TO_ADDException(Exception):
    pass

class TO_ADD:    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            raise TO_ADDException("A TO_ADD is a basic element")
```

---

With some better naming, and improve code

```py
class MaterialException(Exception):
    pass

class Material:
    price: int
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            raise MaterialException("A Material is a basic element and can't receive parameters")
    def calculate_cost(self):
        return self.price

class MaterialContainer(Material):
    def __init__(self, mat: Material):
        super().__init__()
        self.mat = mat
    def calculate_cost(self):
        return self.price + self.mat.calculate_cost()

class Americano(Material):
    price = 60
class Cardamom(MaterialContainer):
    price = 7
class Syrop(MaterialContainer):
    price = 10
```

Use

```
print(Cardamom(Syrop(Americano())).calculate_cost())  # 77
print(Cardamom(Syrop(Syrop(Syrop(Americano())))).calculate_cost())  # 97
print(Cardamom(Syrop(Syrop(Americano(Syrop(1))))).calculate_cost())  # TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `__init__` method for `Americano` which takes an arbitrary number of arguments but raises a custom exception if the number of arguments is not 0:

```
class Americano(TO_ADD):
    price = 60

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            raise MyCustomException('Americano must come first')
```